# How to change alignment of columns in datatable in r shinydashboard?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a dataTableOutput in a shiny dashboard. All the columns are left aligned by default and I want to change it to center align. I am using the following code in my server.R file for the same:

```
output$data<- renderDataTable({data()},
                            options = list(
                             columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = '_all'))))
```

This code is not showing any error but the alignment is not changing. I have searched a lot but the only way to do this seems to be the one I am using. Is there any way to change the alignment? Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [helper functions](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) section on DT documentation:

> You can pass arbitrary CSS properties to formatStyle()

See `?formatStyle` for additional info.

```
library(DT)

datatable(diamonds[1:10,1:3]) %>%
  formatStyle('cut', `text-align` = 'center')
```

[image]